# Orientation Change Issue

Tags: ios, ios7, keyboard, orientation

When switching between portrait and landscape orientation, one of my views (UIButton) disappears and I am at a loss as to why or how.  What I do know is that:

- Its frame remains the same (both origin and size)
- It is not being set as hidden, nor is the alpha changing
- It is not being removed from superview
- It is not being inserted below any views
- Its parent view remains unaffected
- The issue only occurs when text prediction is present above the keyboard (iOS 7.1 Japanese keyboard), but the prediction area is not covering the button

I realize that this post is a little vague, but at the moment I am unsure of what other information may or may not be relevant.  I even placed the frame check in a timer to ensure that it was not being somehow changed by another method.

Answer (score 0):

I was setting the status bar and navbar to hidden, and it was modifying the rest of my constraints.  Instead of hiding them, I am now setting their alphas to 0, which is fortunately an option for me in this case.